# How to get conflicting email address from Firebase Login Error

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I have `Sign in With Facebook` and `Sign In with Google` on my React Web App.

Now, if the user has signed in before using Facebook and then later on wants to sign in with Google with same email address as that of his Facebook account firebase sends back this error message:

> An account already exists with the same email address from another provider

My question now is how do I get the email address from the error object so I can give my users a better error message?

Here is my code:

```
   const handleFacebookSignIn = () => {
    let provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then((result) => {
            //Handle success
        }).catch((error) => {
            let errorMessage = error.message;
            if (errorMessage.toLowerCase().includes("An account already exists with the same 
             email address".toLowerCase())) {
                errorMessage = "Please sign in with your google account"; //How can I get the email address from the error object?
            }
            toast.error(errorMessage);
        });
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: *How can I get the email address from the error object?* -- Is it in the error object?? What does the object look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out which provider has (or providers have) an entry for a given email address, you can [call `firebase.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#fetchsigninmethodsforemail). This allows you to start the correct sign-in flow, once a user has entered their email address.

There is no way in the client-side SDKs to directly look up the UID based on an email address. If that is required for your use-case (which is oft-requested, but not very often really necessary once you know of `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`) the functionality *does* exist in the Admin SDKs, so you can wrap that in a custom API endpoint on your server or i Cloud Functions - securing access to that as you see fit.